# How to use preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins in nested views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

I'm trying to make used of `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` through a nested view hierarchy but hitting a lot of issues with UIKit and wondering what I am doing wrong (or whether this is a genuine bug).

I'm trying to lay out a handful of views (some by the side of each other, some above each other) like so:

```
// Various combinations here will create different visual results (it will either work or won't)

let i1 = ImageView()
//let i1 = LabelView()
let i2 = ImageView()
//let i2 = LabelView()
let i3 = ImageView()
//let i3 = LabelView()

let view = LeftRight(left: i1, right: TopBottom(top: i2, bottom: i3))
//let view = LeftRight(left: TopBottom(top: i2, bottom: i3), right: i1)
```

With some layout's I can get it to work, shown below. You can see that the images on the right are correctly indented against the green view, which is in turn correctly indented against the white view.

[image: Correctly embedded]

But with others I am struggling:

[image: Black screen!]

Running code similar to this in an app I can get a complete lockup and memory runaway.

The indenting is done using `layoutMargins` like this:

```
let masterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
masterView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
masterView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)

let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
subView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)
```

Here's a sample of the image layout from a playground. **[The full playground project can be found here](https://github.com/samskiter/Demo-broken-preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)** and can easily be loaded up and ran in XCode to see what I mean.

```
class ImageView: UIView {

    init() {

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))

        self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
        self.layoutMargins = .zero

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "jesus"))
        imageView.contentMode = .center

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        self.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is in the "others" case. You are only showing us a black screen but no code. Can you please add some details to it?

Comment: the code is all in the playground. It's quite a lot, so i've only shown the basics here. The black screen is because the layout system just seems to fail to render!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you forgot something those are required.

1. Implementation of `intrinsicContentSize` on ImageView and Label
2. Missing constraints that make both subviews have the same width and height in those 2 UIView subclasses (TopBottom and LeftRight)
3. right view of view (LeftRight) still haven't been set its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false
4. Add the `constraint for bottom` of the outmost `frame` view
5. Call `layoutIfNeeded()` on `frame` view

   top.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom.widthAnchor).isActive = true
   top.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom.heightAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: the right of the LeftRight view does have it set to false: `right.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: I have tried to implement `intrinsicContentSize` before posting this question but couldn't get it to work... Also, why should I need to set the width and heights to be the same in the leftRight/topBottom views?

Comment: Because for the Auto Layout engine can't determine the width of both views in Left/Right and the height in Top/Bottom using just your current constraints.

Comment: In the case of the TopBottom, the content hugging of the content causes the view to be as high as the content. - the height is just the top height plus the bottom height and implementing `intrinsicContentSize` is not necessary (although it did try to and it didn't work). Even if you remove the `trailingAnchor` from masterView, it still comes out with just a black screen. Have you got it working your side?

Comment: my labels within my views all have intrinsic content size and width, they are then constrained onto their parents, so there isn't anything ambiguous about the layout once you remove the trailingAnchor from masterView (which as I mentioned, didn't work for me)

Comment: OK then your TopBottom and LeftRight views and calculate their size based on their contents but what will happen when both of their contents have a difference size? That will cause the unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

I think you should try to use equalToOrGreaterThan constraints in your TopBottom and LeftRight views

Comment: Or try adding this constraint `top.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom.widthAnchor).isActive = true` to your TopBottom

Comment: ah sorry, so you mean the *width* of the views in the TopBottom and the *height* in the LeftRight. Yes I agree that in real situations you may need the greaterThan constraints. But the intrinsic hugging constraint will just get broken for the smaller of the two views. I've tried your solution but still can't get it working

Comment: You also forgot these 2 lines


  frameSubview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frame.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  frame.layoutIfNeeded()


before `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = frame`

Comment: The frame is just a large view to display the content. the content should self-size

Comment: However, calling `layoutIfNeeded` does sometimes allow it to layout. interestingly I still need to set a large frame in the init to get some of the layouts to work

Comment: Well I think you should try it in the app (simulator). This might be a bug in Playground

Comment: "Running code similar to this in an app I can get a complete lockup and memory runaway."

I originally found this in an app and boiled it down in a Playground

Comment: Oh that's interesting

Comment: I think you're encountering the `Layout Feedback Loop` problem. You can find more information about this and how to investigate and debug them in 
`https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/`

Comment: Really interesting talk. I do have one of those, going to attempt to debug it now

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found your issue. Your master view and your subview have both a frame of size 500x500 and a marginLayout of 5 points per edge. If you instantiate those with a frame of `.zero` then everything should be fine.

**Update**

After taking a bit more time with your Playground I also added this to ImageView:

```
private var imageView: UIImageView!
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return imageView?.intrinsicContentSize ?? .zero
}
```

and LabelView:

```
private var textLabel: UILabel!
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return textLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? .zero
}
```

Now in your init methods of both `ImageView` and `LabelView` use these instance properties instead of a local variable. After doing so it seems that all possible combinations work. If you had one specific combination that you knew it didn't please let me know so I can test it.

Comment: hi there thanks for having a look. Did you try this solution because I was initially using .zero and it wasn't working as well? By setting the frame I was actually able to get it working slightly more often. They are both laid out with autolayout so the initial frame shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'll update my answer now to add more details. I was about to.

Comment: Hi I've made the changes you describe, but still getting a black screen for this conbination: `let i1 = ImageView() let i2 = LabelView() let i3 = LabelView()`

Comment: Any luck with that combination?